# varImp Function is not giving proper output

Tags: r, r-caret

I have 131 variables out of which I want to get important variables for modelling. I run a decision tree on all variables and then used `caret::varImp` to compute the variable importance, but the output is not appropriate. Below is my code and output.

```
VarImpModel <- rpart(Final_Churn_Flag~.,data=InputData, method = 'class')
varImp(VarImpModel)

               Overall
OnnetAmount   35354.00
TotalARPU     188.96940
Onnet_Fix_AR  144.85092
Age            2.59406
```

Desired output - what I want is:

```
               Overall
OnnetAmount   100.00
TotalARPU      88.96
Onnet_Fix_AR   44.85
Age            22.59
```

Why it is not bound to 100? How to do so?

Comment: Does adding argument `varImp(VarImpModel, scale=TRUE)` get the output you are after?

Comment: The help for varImp.rpart suggests that this method does not use the scale argument `## S3 method for class 'rpart': varImp((object, surrogates = FALSE, competes = TRUE, ...))`. You can always scale the results yourself afterwards, if you are sure this is what you want, but maybe you lose some information that is useful in the original values if you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already using `caret` I'd advise on also training your model from within `caret::train`, as this gives you many more options (e.g. in resampling) - and, as a side effect, scales the variable importance as you need it:

```
> m <- train(x = iris[,1:4], y = iris[,5], method = 'rpart', trControl = trainControl('repeatedcv', number = 10, repeats = 20))
> varImp(m)

rpart variable importance

             Overall
Petal.Width   100.00
Petal.Length   97.57
Sepal.Length   33.53
Sepal.Width     0.00
```